# Remove last-child from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have situation where i have to delete all element(.bxwrapper) except last bxwrapper which is containing ul li from the html for this i have written jquery code which is not working properly please suggest.?

```
<div class="row" id="customBx">
    <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
        <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position:   relative; height: 336px;">
            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
                <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 335px;">
                    <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
                        <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 333px;">
                            <div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 100%;">
                                <div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 331px;">
                                    <ul class="bxslider">
                                        <li class="edSel edBxSlider editBxSlider edRemove" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 990px;"></li>
                                        <li class="edSel edBxSlider editBxSlider edRemove" style="float: left; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 990px;"></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="bx-controls bx-has-controls-direction">
                                    <div class="bx-controls-direction">
<a class="bx-prev" href="">Prev</a><a class="bx-next" href="">Next</a>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.bx-wrapper:not(:last-child)').remove();
</script>
```

Comment: there is only one sub child of bs-wrapper here, so it probably won't remove it, I guess you had a different question in mind

Comment: i want to delete all bx-wrapper except the last vch is containing ul li

Comment: How's it supposed to work? Last child is inside the first child, when you remove the first child last one will be removed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `detach()` so try this:

```
var $lastChild = $('.bx-wrapper').last().detach();
$('#customBx').html($lastChild);
```

Or Simply

```
$('#customBx').html($('.bx-wrapper').last());
```

Comment: first time used detach function

Answer (score 0):

You should first `clone` it then remove them.

```
var list = $('ul.bxslider').clone(true, true);
$('.bx-wrapper').remove();
```

Then append the cloned element to `body` or some other element.

```
$('#customBx').html('<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 331px;"></div>').find('.bx-viewport').append( + list + );
```

Answer (score 0):

You also try with this:

```js
var $lastChildren = $('ul.bxslider').parent().parent('.bx-wrapper').html();
$('#customBx').html($lastChildren);
```

but use into below jquery portion

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Above code
})
```